# Is it appropriate to say Baruch Dayan Ha'emes for someone who commits suicide?

Tags: halacha, blessing, death, suicide

Baruch Dayan Ha'emes is the brachah associated with bad news. More specifically, it has become known as the brachah to say when hearing of the news of someone's passing.

Is it appropriate to say Baruch Dayan Ha'emes when someone commits suicide? On the one hand, someone Jewish died. On the other hand, the person who died killed someone, and their death was itself an act of retzichah.

Comment: There's another side to consider regarding this particular blessing ("the true Judge"), namely the person's death here wasn't due to God's judgement (or at least, not any more so than any other case of death and arguably less so).

Comment: @DoubleAA that's not true in a case of mental illness, and it also applies to someone who was murdered by another person

Comment: @Heshy Perhaps, but arguably here is worse. Arguably too all deaths are the same https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19037/759

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From dinonline:

https://dinonline.org/2012/11/02/dayan-ha-emes-over-suicide/

> One does not recite the “Baruch Dayan Ha-Emet” over a suicide. The reason for this is that the blessing refers to Divine judgment, which is part of His will. In the case of a suicide, death itself is a sin, and this is clearly not Hashem’s will, so that it is inappropriate to recite the blessing (see Yalkut Yosef 56:1).

> This applies specifically to a suicide that is not mourned for, and not to somebody who took his life out of mental disturbance.

Comment: link to yy https://www.yalkut.info/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F-%D7%A0%D7%95-%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%91%D7%93-%D7%A2%D7%A6%D7%9E%D7%95-%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%AA/

Comment: Don't we assume these days that most or all suicides take their own life out of mental disturbance?

Comment: @Mike Every case should be evaluated on its merits. There's no need for assumptions.

Comment: May we not also consider that the person regretted at the last second and tried to stop or reverse?