Is Maimonides' view of free will normative?
Maimonides discusses free will in his Eight Chapters:

"if we should say that God had destined that this sum should pass into the hands of the one and out of the possession of the other, God would be preordaining an act of iniquity" (8:6)


"In making this assertion that obedience or disobedience to the Law of God does not depend upon the power or will of God, but solely upon that of man himself, the sages followed the dictum of Jeremiah, who said, "Out of the mouth of God there cometh neither the bad nor the good". By the words "the bad" he meant vice, and by "the good", virtue; and, accordingly, he maintains that God does not preordain that any man should be vicious or virtuous" (8:7).


"It now remains for us to explain another phase of this problem, which arises from the fact that there are several Scriptural passages in which some think they find proof that God preordains and forces man to disobedience" (8:11).

I don't see how this is possible.  God cannot create creatures that He can't control.  I understand that a lot of people don't want to say that God willed the world in its current state, but that's His prerogative.  I don't think I am misinterpreting him because I don't see why else he would feel the need to provide convoluted explanations of God hardening Pharaoh's heart and other passages. So is this the normative view in Judaism or is Maimonides just wrong here?

Can you reformulate for clarity?

@Nahum  So as far as I can tell Maimonides is saying that God does not predestine people to sin, but this view is illogical.  So is Maimonides at variance with mainstream Judaism on this point?

Not sure what you mean. Free will is the cornerstone of mainstream jewish thought. Cf Mishna Avot 3:15 "Everything is foreseen, yet free will is given.". Are you suggesting that some kind of calvinist predestination is more logical?

@wmasse the debates about free will among rishonim are very extensive. It's a topic riddled with paradoxes and incomplete solutions. It's best summed up, as Nahum did: "Everything is forseen, yet free will is given" i.e. a paradox. Therefore I don't see how it's possible to answer this factually and I VTC as opinion based. Sorry! However, do take a look here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/856/do-we-really-have-free-choice/114432#114432

A master of the chess board knows many possible combinations of moves to be made by each player.  God knows all of the possible moves.

According to the Rambam (More Nevuchim 3:17, fifth view), the view that humans have free will is undisputed in Judaism:

וזאת פינה לא נשמע כלל באומתנו ובאנשי תורתנו חולק עליה

This can be confirmed, for instance, by the agreement of diverse commentators on Avot 3:15.
The Rambam himself acknowledges that this is a very difficult concept to grasp, but nevertheless maintains that it's demonstrably true (Teshuva 5:5). The Raavad, despite criticizing his presentation of the question and (partial) answer, still agrees on the issue of free will.

Though infamously https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordechai_Yosef_Leiner#Thought

@DoubleAA R Chasdai Crescas already espoused such a view. Gersonides goes to the other extreme, affirming free will while denying divine foreknowledge. Somehow Rambam, following Avos, squares them.

@Nahum Stressing God's knowledge isn't denying human free will. R Crescas says humans have free choice qua themselves, not qua God's knowledge (=God knows what people will do, but the people have free choice). He asks the same question the Rambam poses in Hilchot Teshuva, and he offers the Rambam's answer, alongside his own, which he can do because up to there the view is the same (2:5:3). The analysis relies heavily on the Rambam's 19th proposition, which is one of the few that he doesn't attack in part 1 of the book.

An important point to note about Pharaoh and others whom God is said to have hardened their heart - leading to their destruction: none of the sins they committed that merited their destruction were caused by God. It doesn’t say God hardened Pharaoh’s heart that he might kill the sons of Israel, for instance.

Whether or not God could literally suspend someone's free will at some point is another question, but God ultimately determined every sin that we commit because He is the First Cause.  That's why there's no need to get bent out of shape about these passages.

Nothing in scripture asserts that God predetermined our sins, or our actions in general. To the contrary, God gives us a choice and exhorts us to choose life (Deuteronomy 30)
