How can missionary arguments about free will be refuted?
In light of the fact that the majority of Christians including Catholics and Orthodox believe in predestination, as does Islam (in fact, one of Antony Flew's ("the world's most famous atheist") biggest reasons for being an atheist was that he correctly realized that if God exists He would be controlling everyone):
I recently came across the following on chabad.org:

QUESTION: "If everything is predetermined by G‑d, then how should we live?" ANSWER: As it is said, "Everything is in the hand of G-d except the fear of G‑d." There is much that is pre-determined - but not our moral choices. You would have realized this for yourself if you had pushed your questioning one step further, that is: If everything is predetermined by G‑d, then how can He reward us or punish us? The only possible answer is that those aspects in our lives which incur reward or punishment are not under the control of destiny; they are truly free choices.

And this idea has serious support.  For example, Rashi commenting on Sotah 2a says:

“Do they in fact pair them up according to wickedness and merit? But before their formation, when his wickedness and meritoriousness are not known, they announce his match. And if you'll ask that everything is revealed before God, [the answer is that] everything is in the hands of Heaven except for fear of Heaven. As is stated in Tractate Niddah: "the angel appointed over pregnancy takes a drop and brings it before the Omnipresent and says before Him, 'what will be with this drop? Strong or weak? Wise or foolish? Rich or poor?'" But he does not say to Him 'righteous or wicked', since that is not in the hands of Heaven.”

And Maimonides clearly held this view as well:

“However, this is known without any doubt: That man's actions are in his [own] hands and The Holy One, blessed be He, does not lead him [in a particular direction] or decree that he do anything” (Hilchot Teshuva 5:5).


“if we should say that God had destined that this sum should pass into the hands of the one and out of the possession of the other, God would be preordaining an act of iniquity" (Eight Chapters 8:6).


"In making this assertion that obedience or disobedience to the Law of God does not depend upon the power or will of God, but solely upon that of man himself, the sages followed the dictum of Jeremiah, who said, "Out of the mouth of God there cometh neither the bad nor the good". By the words "the bad" he meant vice, and by "the good", virtue; and, accordingly, he maintains that God does not preordain that any man should be vicious or virtuous" (Eight Chapters 8:7).


"It now remains for us to explain another phase of this problem, which arises from the fact that there are several Scriptural passages in which some think they find proof that God preordains and forces man to disobedience" (Eight Chapters 8:11).

The Ra'avad responding to Maimonides said:

“If the righteousness and wickedness of a person were dependent on the decree of God, we would say that His knowledge is His decree and we would have the very difficult question. But now that God has removed this dominion from His hand and given it to the hand of man himself, His knowledge is not a decree; rather, it is like the knowledge of the astrologers who know from another source what the ways of this person will be” (Hilchot Teshuva 5:5).

Gersonides held this view and consequently denied that God knows the future:

“[However,] human choice rules over this arrangement of their actions based on the celestial causes. And it is therefore possible that what people actually do is different from what God knew [they would do] based on the arrangement of their actions” (Commentary on Genesis 18).

This view is also strongly implied by the idea that rulers do not have free will, which seems to imply that if they had free will then God would not be in control of what they do.  This view is also strongly implied by the idea that you shouldn’t pray to be matched with a specific person.  This seems to be based on the notion that if you end up marrying someone because you chose to pray about it using free will then God couldn’t have predestined it.  This also seems to imply that free will is outside of God’s control.
However God is the only First Cause which means that He willed everything about the universe including every decision made with free will.  Any other view is illogical (and polytheist).  So is it OK to say that these commentators acting out of a misguided desire to protect God’s goodness were simply wrong, but it doesn’t matter because Judaism doesn’t have dogmatic teachings about this sort of thing?

Free will is not an invention of the Rabbis, but a pasuk in the Torah. Free will as a concept is notoriously paradoxical, and an unresolved one at that. It's not really fair to use one conclusion about the topic as a weapon against Judaism, which holds a different conclusion. We just accept it on faith, and so to do those who hold free will is impossible/polytheistic etc.

@RabbiKaii  All I'm talking about here is the claim that God doesn't control people's moral decisions, which is objectively false.  Free will is a whole other discussion.

Why do you keep bringing up missionaries? You know we don't do comparative religion. If it's an on-topic question about Judaism, ask the question on its own merit. Presenting it as a missionary argument doesn't give it any weight and only raises questions about your motives.

@wmasse You said “God doesn’t control people’s moral decisions”. You then immediately said “free will is a whole other discussion”. Now take a second to think why we have a problem here. (Hint: focus on the terms “decision” and “free will”).

@wmasse additionally, you can’t make an unsupported claim that something is objectively false in an attempt to disprove an argument that that thing is true. In this case, it is claimed that the freedom of moral choices does exist. Saying “Well no it doesn’t” isn’t a valid argument.

I have upvoted @shmosel's question, because I think it would be very good if it were answered. Particular bizzare because this question seems much more likely to come from atheists than missionaries

@shmosel I don't think it's comparative religion.  If a claim is made about Judaism (in this case that Judaism teaches that God doesn't decide what people do) I want to know whether that claim is true or not.

@Qwertrl  No, I'm saying it's a fact that God does control people's moral decisions.  That doesn't mean that we don't have free will, it just means you have to incorporate that in your idea of free will (i.e. from our perspective we have free will but not from God's)

@Qwertrl  I know I didn't give evidence to back that claim up, but the question is whether that claim is compatible with orthodox Judaism or if there's room for differing opinions.

@RabbiKaii  Not so.  The majority of Christians including Catholics and Orthodox believe in predestination, as does Islam.  In fact, one of Antony Flew's ("the world's most famous atheist") biggest reasons for being an atheist was that he correctly realized that if God exists He would be controlling everyone.

@wmasse Free will is the freedom to want something as opposed to another. In other words, it is the ability to will independently. Free will exists. So does השגחה פרטית (complete Divine control). It’s always been known that the two apparently contradict each other, despite both being required by scripture. Wanna know how? Sucks, because God created knowledge, and He doesn’t have to make one of His creations conform to your beliefs about logic. Your inability to comprehend the existence of a paradox does not mean that every Rabbi who lived before you is wrong.

[cont’d] It’s known that paradoxes exist, and the fact that this one arises from scripture instead of from pure mathematics doesn’t mean it can’t exist.

@Qwertrl The quotes I gave don't sound like they believe in complete divine control.

@wmasse the quotes you gave represent attempts at logically reconciling free will with the concept of complete divine control. If anything, those quotes can be taken as proof of the fact that their authors held that both concepts are completely true. The only one that even seems like it might disagree somewhat with complete divine control, is the last one, by Gersonides.

Do some research into Izhbitzer philosophy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordechai_Yosef_Leiner?wprov=sfti1#Thought

@Yø-cRo  I'm confused, the Izhbitzer certainly held that ultimately God controls people's choices, so why does everyone on here seem to think this is heresy?

@wmasse The Izhbitzer never truly says that there is no free will; in fact, he says the opposite several times (see e.g. Parshas Haazinu s.v. ה לה׳ תגמלו זאת). He does generally take a very nuanced view on free will, but the fact that it exists is indisputable in mainstream Judaism.

@Yø-cRo This question was not meant to be about the nature of free will, but only whether or not the belief that moral decisions were predestined by God is part of Judaism.  It sounds like the Izhbitzer as well as Crescas agree with this, so I am confused by some of the answers given. Is there room for differing opinion about this?

@wmasse The problem with your question is your list of questionable premises, with the final question being “is it ok to say that anyone who disagrees with these premises is wrong?” I’m sure the reaction would be very different if you would ask “what is the Jewish view on predeterminism”.

@Yø-cRo I was expecting someone to say that Judaism does believe in predeterminism and that the sources I quoted actually don't contradict predeterminism. As far as I can tell the common belief is that moral actions aren't predetermined but there are some who disagree.

The premise of this question is unfounded. You write "However God is the only First Cause which means that He willed everything about the universe including every decision made with free will. Any other view is illogical (and polytheist)." This claim does not withstand scrutiny.
G-d willed everything in the universe into existence, including a being that can make free choices, Man. That is what "created in in the image of G-d" means. G-d provides Man with multiple options and allows him/her to choose among them. G-d provides Man with the space to make these choices (G-d's will is necessary to effectuate those choices but the choices are Man's).
The Torah expressly states this idea in Deuteronomy 30:15-20.

רְאֵ֨ה נָתַ֤תִּי לְפָנֶ֙יךָ֙ הַיּ֔וֹם אֶת־הַֽחַיִּ֖ים וְאֶת־הַטּ֑וֹב וְאֶת־הַמָּ֖וֶת וְאֶת־הָרָֽע
... וּבָֽחַרְתָּ֙ בַּחַיִּ֔ים לְמַ֥עַן תִּֽחְיֶ֖ה אַתָּ֥ה וְזַרְעֶֽךָ
See I have placed before you live and good and death and evil ... And you should choose life in order that you and your offspring shall live.

You've asserted that this position is illogical and polytheist but have provided no argument to support that position. Moreover, everyone (or nearly so) alive experiences free will on a regular basis.
Isn't it more likely that a universally experienced phenomenon exists and you just don't understand how it works, than it doesn't exist and G-d's just creating an illusion for his automatons to go through life deluding themselves that they can make choices?

Appreciated, but my question was more about whether or not the view that God controls everyone is compatible with orthodox Judaism, because I know there are differing opinions about some of these things.

@wmasse the view that humans cannot make choices is not compatible with orthodox Judaism as far as I know. Nor is it compatible with the Torah.

I don't think the fact that God controls everyone necessarily prevents us from having a genuine experience of free will from our perspective.

@wmasse our “experience” is irrelevant. If I hypnotize you (movie-style), without your consent, to rob a bank, then I—not you—should be the one punished. You had no choice in the matter, and thus, punishing you would be both illogical and futile, since you weren’t the perpetrator, but the non-consenting tool. If anything, you should be compensated: Had you not been hypnotized, you surely would never have done anything bad, and you’d likely regret having stolen. Your emotions and beliefs during hypnosis don’t logically bring about reward or punishment. It’s completely inane to think otherwise.

@Qwertrl But earlier you said "their authors held that both concepts are completely true." If you meant free will and complete divine control then that makes sense (although they really dont sound like they believe in complete divine control).  But if by free will you mean that God didn't decide from eternity what sins people would commit, then that's simply impossible because it's just affirming and negating the same statement.

@Qwertrl Also being able to create beings with free will is a power that only God has because of things like divine simplicity and omnipotence.  God doesn't need to use instruments to bring about His will. Unlike the hypnotist God can cause an effect with no inherent connection to a created cause.

@wmasse We can make free choices but whether those free choices manifest in the world is up to G-d, not us. If Bob choose to murder Tim, G-d may deprive Bob of the ability to take action on that decision but Bob still made that choice and will receive divine judgment for it. The choice is free, the action in the world is under G-d's control.

@conceptualinertia That explanation also sounds like it's implying that there are things that God doesn't control.

@wmasse Yes. G-d doesn't control our choices (he can but chooses not to).

@wmasse What’s happening here is very simple: You, understandably, have a problem with the idea that there’s something Hashem doesn’t control, because Hashem is omnipotent. But you fail to recognize that Hashem, being omnipotent, has the ability to not control something if He so desires. Your stated beliefs, not those of every Rabbi in the past few millennia, are internally dissonant.

@Qwertrl In any case, if my view is unorthodox then why is this on Sefaria? https://www.sefaria.org/Mei_HaShiloach?tab=contents

@wmasse Rav Leiner’s view on free will was extremely unorthodox. Your line of thought is not unique, nor is it accepted by a large percentage of Orthodoxy. Finding one single source that agrees with you does not validate your reasoning.

@wmasse Not all of the works on Sefaria are Orthodox. That being said, the Ishbitzer is generally viewed as being Orthodox despite this theoretically antinomian view.This is because, despite this view, the Ishbitzer and his followers continued to adhere to strict religious practices of Hasidic Judaism. I suspect, very strongly, that the Ishbitzer did not actually believe the opinion attributed to him but used it as a way of explaining how to sinners should not despair from their past deeds.

That claim is totally incompatible with Judaism.
Reward and punishment are the result of moral choices. If those choices weren’t ours to make, we wouldn’t get reward or punishment, and thus a fundamental part of Judaism—referenced explicitly a multitude of times in scripture¹—would be impossible. See רמב״ם in משנֶה תורה, הִלְכוֹת תשובה, פרק ה׳ (from ״אִלּו הַאֵל היה גוזר…״).
¹e.g:
Genesis 4:7, קַיְן can make the moral choice to repent;
Leviticus 26:2–45, blessings and curses depend on the explicitly-conditional moral choices of the nation;
Deuteronomy 11:13-28, where the Jews are given a moral decision with its consequences laid out in detailed form, and then (in Parashat Re’eh) in abstract form;
Deuteronomy 30:15–20, where the Jews are given another explicit moral choice in order to mentally prepare them before entering the land;
Joshua 24:14–15, where Joshua tells the Jews to make a moral decision regarding their loyalty to G-D.

+1 Surprised you didn't bring Rambam Hilchot Teshuva who brings your exact point :)

@RabbiKaii Good point; I’ll add that. When I first wrote the answer, I thought it was such a logical concept that it didn’t need a source. But then again, if that were the case, this question wouldn’t have been asked. (And thanks for the +1!)

@Qwertrl You're assuming that God controlling people's actions is mutually exclusive with free will.  Also in your comment to my question you said that all of the quoted sources do believe in complete divine control.  Complete divine control is not mutually exclusive with free will unless you think free will means that God had not control over it.

@wmasse Right here, in a comment, define free will for us. Define it precisely, just as you understand it.

@Qwertrl Free will means you genuinely could have chosen differently (from your perspective).  That means if A > B where A is everything that led up to that decision and B is the decision, there is no necessary connection between them, so it could've been A > C and been just as intelligible.  So acts of free will are almost like bare instances of God's will like the number of atoms in the universe or something like that.  That's how we can have the "illusion" that we really could have chosen differently and hence why we can be justly punished.

@wmasse Thank you. Please elaborate on the logical connection between the second-to-last sentence and what comes before it, and between that and the last sentence. I don’t see how they follow each other.

@Qwertrl  I don't want to go off on tangents here.  The question is just about the statement "God decided from eternity what sins I would commit."  I want to know what Judaism's view of this claim is.

@wmasse Judaism’s view of that claim is that it’s entirely, utterly, and absolutely false, because of A) direct scriptural proof, and B) a very simple logical derivation from the fact of free will. I’m attempting to understand why you don’t agree with reason B, which, in my mind, can only arise from a non-traditional understanding of the term “free will”.

@Qwertrl I don't think the statement in question is really debatable due to first Cause arguments and the like.  However I'm not sure that this view is outside the pale of Judaism, see for example Hasdai Crescas's view in this question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/856/do-we-really-have-free-choice

@wmasse Again, you can’t disprove an argument by claiming that you’re right. You can’t just dismiss the traditional approach, and claim that your opinion is correct for the sole reason that you “don’t think [it] is really debatable”. That’s not how it works. Jews find the truth by asking a hundred questions, figuring out all possible answers, and logically debating which ones are correct until the truth is agreed upon. We never just dismiss an opinion because we don’t understand it. That’s not okay. If that’s what you want to do, Mi Yodeya isn’t for you.

Anyone bothered by how mans free will can coexist with god has bigger questions he should be asking. Such as why the existence of the finite world isn’t a direct refutation of an infinite god.  The answer of course is that god can do anything. If that answers not good enough for you, then good, you’re a healthy human that doesn’t fully grasp the infinite god.

One line answer: the Jewish picture is that we only have free will when it comes to our relationship with God/morality.

In a world where it feels like we have absolutely no control, so many people have been struggling with the concept of free choice.
When we think about it, most of the choices that people make on daily basis are not FREE at all.
They are pragmatic decisions, based on a risk-benefit analysis, influenced by one’s personality and nature.
This is not what we are referring to when we talk about free choice from a Torah perspective.
G-d does not want to control us; He wants us to have independence.
But the only area where our choice really matters is in our relationship with Him.
What He wants is for us to choose Him.
And this is where our free choice lies. Hence, "all is in the hands of heaven, except fear of heaven", i.e. except when it comes to our relationship with Hashem.
See this lecture, "Is G-d Controlling You? The Truth About Our Freedom Of Choice", for more information. Rabbi Friedman's team recently sent this in an email, with the above blurb (which I have edited partially).
